# How do I change the OS X Mouse Pointer's color?

Tags: macos, mouse, accessibility

I have some visual impairment, and I often have problems finding my mouse pointer on the screen.  I want to change the color of the pointer.

I know in "Universal Access" you can change the size, but it still doesn't help that the cursor 'blends in' with everything else on my screen.  I want to make my cursor bright green or red.

I'm using OS X 10.6.7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Anything that allows you to change the color is paid software. Here's [MightyMouse.](http://unsanity.com/haxies/mightymouse)</strike>
Unfortunately, it looks like MightyMouse has been discontinued :(

I would recommend this ***free*** software that displays a circle around your cursor. When you haven't moved your mouse for awhile and you move it, it'll display a circle around the pointer. [Here's](http://www.2point5fish.com/) the software.

Comment: This is very convenient, free, and user friendly. I wish it was 64 bit, but it does run just fine in Lion.  Wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

I think this application may help you:

### [Mouseposé](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Omnidazzle you can not change the color, like I want to but you can see a thing round the mouse to find it by pressing a key. Try it.

Comment: Can you provide links or screenshots that clearly identify why the OP would want to use this program?

Comment: Omnidazzle is no longer supported and does not work well on modern hardware.